# MySQL INSERT statement not executed

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I cannot for the love of god figure out why this statement is not executing. When I limit it to

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO my_pets() VALUES ()", $con);
```

it fires just fine, creating an empty row (NULL in every cell), but as soon as I give it columns and values, it refuses. See below.

Can someone point out a mistake or any other reason this (seemingly) correct code isn't firing when columns and values are specified?

**Premises:**

- $h, $un, $pw, and $db are all fine, as I have copied it from documents that work as we speak.
- There are no typos or mistakes in upper/lower case characters of column names and such.

**The code:**

```
<?php

session_start();

$h="...";      // Host name
$un="...";     // Mysql username
$pw="...";     // Mysql password
$db="...";     // Database name

$con = mysql_connect("$h", "$un", "$pw")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db")or die("cannot select DB");

$name = "Pip";
$gender = "F";
$species = "Dog";

mysql_query("INSERT INTO my_pets (name, gender, species) VALUES ('$name', '$gender', '$species')", $con);

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Table create statement?

Comment: What is the table structure? What does *it refuses* mean? (An actual error message would be better).

Comment: Table simply consists of rows that expect only varchar values with a limit of 255, and of course an id-column (primary key).

Comment: Try backticking `name`, as it's a mysql reserved word.

Comment: I'm sorry, Shiranai7, I get no error message anywhere. Is there a way to force it, or am I not looking in the right places?

Comment: That did the trick, Dont Panic. You're a hero.

Comment: Can I mark it as resolved somewhere? (I'm new here)

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you! I haven't added an answer because I think the question may be a duplicate (sorry!) I haven't found the duplicate to link to yet, though.

Comment: The linked question isn't specifically about `name`, but it's the same principle, and the answer should be applicable.

Comment: You also should check out prepared statements, because if you take user input for the query you will be vulnerable for sql injections. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Also, I misspoke. It's a keyword, but not a reserved word.

Comment: @Don'tPanic ^ correct https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: @VHK In order to be absolutely sure, you need to do `or die(mysql_error())` against `mysql_query()`. Then come back and give us the real error.

Comment: What settings or what MySQL version is forcing to use backtics for `name` in a column list? It's working on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74c52/1) and has always worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Obtained from [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), If you're using PHP 7.0.0, `mysql_query` will no longer work:

**Warning**
This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
mysqli_query()
PDO::query()

**Good / Important note from someone who cares:** This function should not be used for any future code and should be replaced for existing code, so I would recommend you change to PDO.

Comment: I don't disagree with any of this, but it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @Don'tPanic If he is using php 7.0.0 it would answer it though. This might possibly not be the reason, but it's possible it is :)

Comment: At the beginning of the question, OP says that `mysql_query` works without columns and values. That wouldn't be the case if the function didn't exist. Although I guess that could be the case for a future reader.